# How to use Node.js to change current working directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, operating-system

I want to make an alias manager using node.js for easy distribution with npm. 
Is it possible to change the working directory outside of the program context using node? My current solution is to use `exec("start cmd.exe /K cd " + shortcutPath);` to open a new command line window. However, I want to change the directory without starting a new `cmd` process.

An example of the ideal output is below

```
C:\Users\Documents> [some command]
|||||||||||program running|||||||||||
C:\Users\Documents\subfolder>
```

Comment: If you're just trying to change the current working directory in the current command shell, why not just use a batch file?  If you're trying to change it within the node.js program only, then use [`process.chdir()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_chdir_directory).

Comment: If I were to run the batch file from within the node.js program, would the working directory change once the program finished running? How would I do so?

Comment: I meant to run your node program from a batch file where the first line changes the directory.  If you want to change the directory from within the node program, use `process.chdir()`.

Comment: I don't know if it would change for after the program runs.  It would take you but a few minutes to test it.  If you change it before in a batch file that then runs your nodejs program, the change would be in effect for after your program runs.  Or just change it after running your program in the batch file (I can't honestly tell exactly what behavior you want).